# Probability number is divisible by 11

Tags: probability

[image]

In this how they have written $x+y=14$ and $x-y=11\lambda$ . what is the use of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just commenting on the use of $x,y$ in the answer you provided, it appears $x$ refers to the sum of odd digits and $y$ refers to the sum of even digits. Hence, $x+y=41$ by the statement. On the other hand, for any number that is divisible by $11$, the difference between the sum of its odd digits and the sum of its even digits is be divisible by $11$. Hence $x-y=11\cdot \lambda$ for some integer $\lambda$.

Comment: We count odd places from left or right

Comment: From right to left. So for example, in $138572$, the odd digits are $2,5,3$.

Comment: @user123733 It doesn't make any difference if the given number has an odd number of digits.